# How to use onFrameUpdate in lua?

Tags: events, lua, listener, coronasdk

I want to do something with event listener in lua, this is for example :

```
function onTouch(event)
    if(event.target.frame == 2) then
        event.target:setFrame(1)
    elseif(event.target.frame == 3) then
        bar:setFrame(bar.frame + 1)
        event.target:setFrame(1)
        event.target:play()
    end
end
```

those if-end will work when object is in touch, but how I want that thing work when frame change ? I try onFrameChange but there's nothing happened.

Thanks before, im newbie :D

Comment: This is perhaps corona? If so you'll probably have more luck if you add the corona tag

Answer (score 0):

You need the [enterFrame](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/index.html) listener

```
function printTimeSinceStart( event )
    if(object.frame == 2) then
        object:setFrame(1)
    elseif(object.frame == 3) then
        bar:setFrame(bar.frame + 1)
        object:setFrame(1)
        object:play()
    end
end 
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", onEnterFrame)
```